# PhaseListener doesn't work in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I implemented a PhaseListener as explained in this solution:
[ViewExpiredException not thrown on ajax request if JSF page is protected by j_security_check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504131/viewexpiredexception-not-thrown-on-ajax-request-if-jsf-page-is-protected-by-j-se)

this works fine in Firefox, Chrome, but it doesn't in IE9; method afterPhase is just not executed... I also tried adding compatibility for IE but still fails...

Has anyone has faced the same problem?

I'm working with Primefaces 4 and Spring security...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. Problem was the browser cache.
There are several ways to disable the browser cache. I implemented a solution as explained in the answer for this question: 
[javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored) ...